# Apple Maps Link Opens in Safari before native app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, maps

I am running into a little issue in which Safari is opening before directly launching into the native Apple Maps app in Xamarin. I followed this tutorial somewhat: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/native-map-app

```
        var locationUrl = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ?
            $"http://maps.apple.com/?q={address}" :
            $"http://maps.google.com/?q={address}";

        var uri = new Uri( locationUrl ).AbsoluteUri;

        try
        {
            await Launcher.OpenAsync( uri );
        }

        catch
        {
            await AppState.Current.NavigateToExternalBrowserAsync( uri );
        }
```

This works perfectly in Android and launches directly into the native application. I followed this apple maps scheme: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what the documentation says in the archives and prior answers, the maps:// scheme seems to create the behavior I anticipated.,

So, updating the Apple URI to:

```
$"maps://http://maps.apple.com/?q={address}"
```

Works beautifully.

The entire snippet:

```
        var locationUrl = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ?
        $"maps://http://maps.apple.com/?q={address}" :
        $"http://maps.google.com/?q={address}";

        var uri = new Uri( locationUrl );
        try
        {
            await Launcher.OpenAsync( locationUrl );
        }

        catch
        {
            await AppState.Current.NavigateToExternalBrowserAsync( uri.AbsoluteUri );
        }
```

creates the anticipated behavior of opening natively in the maps application without safari as an intermediary. The only downside is that if a user is on an Apple device and has uninstalled the maps app (which is speculatively rare), it will prompt them to restore the maps application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is Apple's intention. From [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html):

> Map links are specified as regular `http` links and are opened either in Safari or the Maps app on the target platform.

If it briefly opens in Safari it is most likely recognizing the URI inside the browser and porting it to the app (like how you can "Open in App" with some websites, except this is automatic).

Comment: Even that line in the documentation entails that it should be able to open directly in the maps app on the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html):
Unlike some schemes, map URLs do not start with a “maps” scheme identifier. Instead, map links are specified as regular http links and are opened either in Safari or the Maps app on the target platform.