# How to launch apple maps with multiple stops in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, url, maps

I was able to launch apple maps using `url_launcher` package with this url  `"https://maps.apple.com/?saddr=18.519513,73.868315&daddr=18.518496,73.879259"`

But I am unable to find any resource or a way to have stops in between the source and destination. Is it possible for apple maps to have multiple stops between source and destination? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Multiple stops in Apple Maps was introduced in iOS 16, but the documentation for MapLinks is not updated. Does someone know if it this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By passing multiple `daddr` query string parameters you can setup a mutli stop trip, I couldn't find this documented anywhere however.

Example:

```
https://maps.apple.com/?dirflg=d&daddr=OXFORD%2C%20FL%2034484&daddr=FRANKLIN%2C%20TN%2037064
```

[image: Apple Maps directions with 10 stops]

Comment: Prefixing the URI with `maps` avoids it initially opening in the browser, e.g. `maps://https://maps.apple.com/`, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72351317/556600

Comment: This doesn't work. It only gives you directions to the last daddr

Comment: @BrianLorraine I've updated my answer with a screenshot showing it working.

Comment: You're right. It works. I had to upgrade from 15 to 16